# gdb in emacs hangs when issuing the 'q(uit)' command

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb

I'm using emacs 24.5.1 under Mac Yosemite, in graphical mode and I'm trying to get gdb 7.11 working.

After starting gdb with 'gdb', I use 'r' to run a mini C++ code, consisting only of an empty main(), which exits normally. After it exits I can type 'r' again and the program will run and exit fine again. However, when I type 'q' to quit gdb, I get a newline without the (gdb) prompt, but gdb does not seem to have quit; It no longer responds to input, but when I try invoking gdb again, emacs tells me that 'this program is already being debugged'.

```
Current directory is ~/cpp/ppcpp/
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...Reading symbols from /Users/mwisse/cpp/ppcpp/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out...done.
done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/mwisse/cpp/ppcpp/a.out 
[Inferior 1 (process 98675) exited normally]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/mwisse/cpp/ppcpp/a.out 
[Inferior 1 (process 98677) exited normally]
(gdb) q
...This is me typing something to show I can type anything here...
but no response.
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out what caused the issue, but it went away after replacing my .emacs.d directory with the one mentioned here: http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-for-proglang.html.